# Drupal 7 webform send Markup component through email

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

How do I send Webform Markup component using `%get[key]` through Email?

Comment: Do you mean you want Webform Markup field to be accessible through `%value[key]` or `%email[key]`? Or are you looking for a specific use case for `%get[key]` like http://drupal.org/node/1156694?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Use %value[key] instead.